# Access results of a fingerprint scan on iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, fingerprint, touch-id

I would like to make an app that will recognise it's users by fingerprints.
I would like to scan the user fingerprint and then store it somewhere as a hash or hashable object. That way I can authenticate multiple users on one device.

Is it possible to access the data of a fingerprint scan on iPhone with iOS9?

Comment: The TouchID fingerprint? No, there's no API, the thing is closed.

Comment: You can't do this directly. The user can enroll multiple fingerprints in iOS, and then you can use `LAContext` and `LAPolicy` to validate that one of those fingerprints was gathered, but you can't get direct access to the fingerprint data or know which one was used. You'll just get "yes, a biometric authentication was successful."